Kalman Filter to enforce constraints or norm penalization on kalman gain
I am running a large filter with numerous states and observations. However, I have a strong prior belief that the entries in my Kalman Gain matrix should be positive. In practice, some entries may turn out negative due to collinearity issues. I want to enforce positive signs or, at the very least, control the norm of the Kalman Gain matrix.
Is there an existing efficient algorithm that can help me enforce this constraint? I can certainly add a constraint to this optimization problem to minimize the trace of $P$ when solving for $K$
$$\begin{align}
  \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k} & = \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} \mathbf{H}_k^\textsf{T} \mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{K}_k \left(\mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} \mathbf{H}_k^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{R}_k\right) \mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T} \\[6pt]
                       &= \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} \mathbf{H}_k^\textsf{T} \mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{S}_k\mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T}
\end{align}$$
$$\frac{\partial \; \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{P}_{k\mid k})}{\partial \;\mathbf{K}_k} = -2 \left(\mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1}\right)^\textsf{T} + 2 \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{S}_k = 0$$
but that for sure seems very computationally expensive when we no longer use a closed-form analytical solution but an optimizer.. Is there an existing solution to this?

What you're after is called Non Negative Least Squares.
In general, it doesn't have a closed form solution.
Since you have a good starting point, I'd use few iterations of Projected Gradient Descent.
The motivation is due to the fact the projections is simple.
The algorithm:

Solve the LS solution (The classic solution for $\boldsymbol{K}$).
It will be used as the initial solution $\boldsymbol{K}^{0}$.
Update (Gradient Descent Step): $\boldsymbol{K}^{i} = \boldsymbol{K}^{i - 1} - \mu \left( -2 \left( \boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{P} \right)^\textsf{T} + 2 \boldsymbol{K}^{i - 1} \boldsymbol{S} \right)$.
Project into non negative values: $\boldsymbol{K}^{i}_{i, j} = \max \left\{ 0, \boldsymbol{K}^{i}_{i, j} \right\}$.
Namely, clip the values of the matrix into the non negative values.
Check for convergence.

Probably only few iterations will be needed and you will get the optimal Non Negative LS solution.

@ChenChen, You may use backtracking which will find it adaptively. One could extract it analytically by the spectrum of the operator. Yet I'd go the backtracking trick.

@ChenChen, The projection will handle the constraint. To set the step size $\mu$ you use the same backtracking trick used in any gradient descent method.
